# Modifying quart.request - acceptable? (Python API)

Tags: python, quart

I need to store some per-request metrics and telemetry (such as timestamps, etc) in [quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/) (the python web framework). Is it acceptable behaviour to modify `quart.request` and add variables?

It appears to work, and it's similar to how I would have done it in Flask but I'm not sure if it is considered bad practice in `Quart`.

The background is that I want to store fine-grained telemetry (namely time stamps for when certain things happen inside a request) and not just the total request time.

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, best to extend the Request class and then assign this new class to the `request_class` attribute on the [app object](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/-/blob/master/src/quart/app.py#L162)